# kerberos in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, iis, kerberos

Can anyone let me know how kerberos works with IIS, I can see the option of enabling "Use Kerberos" in IIS but not sure how it exactly works.
How can I verify that the connection uses kerberos, is there any tool?

Basically I need to authenticate user using kerberos authentication in asp.net. Reading some articles I can see windows domain controller itself uses kerberos authentication, so If I enable kerberos in IIS, does it actually use kerberos?

Please guide me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A great start is using the tool that the IIS team supplied a few years ago called DelegConfig http://blogs.iis.net/bretb/archive/2008/03/27/How-to-Use-DelegConfig.aspx, this will walk you through all the necessary steps to utilize Kerberos with IIS.

Kerberos helps you to manage network hops by using constrained delegation to certain "SPNs" (Service Principle Names) - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc961723.aspx

I found knowing about that tool and what an SPN and constrained delegation are to be the most useful things in understanding how Kerberos works with IIS. Learning by doing is the most effective way to cement the knowledge in my opinion.

Comment: I'll try it out and let you know.